# Enter keydown on google map triggers wrong action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps api to create a map on a webpage with Javascript in ASP.net.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=nl

**On the map is a searchbox where the user can type a town and when he hits enter the map should go to that location**. Currently it only works when the user clicks on the searchresults and not when he hits enter.

Pressing the enter button when focussed on the map activates a search box in the header and goes to the resultpage of this search instead of showing the desired location on the map.

Maybe a little catch: I can't change anything from the search in the header.

I've looked a while on the internet and found options to disable the keydown on the map for now, but this is not want I want as endresult.

I know there are similar topics on stack but I can't seem to get it working.
Can anyone help me on this matter?

Thanks in advance!

The header search box:

```
   <input name="test_Keywords" type="text" id="test_Keywords" class="dtSearchTextField">
   <input type="submit" name="test_SubmitButton" value="Zoek" id="test_SubmitButton" title="Zoek" class="testSubmit">
```

The google maps with search box:

```
    <input id="pac-input" name="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="coordinates or location">
    <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    window.google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
        (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '100%';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '600px';
    var map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.2476303285567, 4.684553057304344),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.controls[window.google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[window.google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Set search restriction options
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: "be"
        }
    };

    var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    //var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    ///** @type {HTMLInputElement} */input, options);

    var markers = [];

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = searchBox.getPlace();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
        markers = [];
        var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new window.google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        markers.push(marker);

        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would surely help us to see what happens.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I can't reproduce the entire scenario in js fiddle because it is build in Asp.net and involves a lot of different files. The main issue is that keydown on the map does not trigger the map to change locations.

Comment: Can you provide a working URL?

Comment: @MrUpsidown It is local on my machine :(

Comment: I don't understand the 2 inputs. Can you clarify? Also what do you mean here: *"Pressing the enter button when focussed on the map [...]"* Try to make your question as clear as possible when a working example cannot be provided.

Comment: When the focus is on the search box of the google maps and you press enter normally the wanted location is shown, like in the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=nl, when I do this the search box in the header is activated.   

The two inputs from the header search are just a textbox and button the create a 'searchform'.

Comment: You are misleading with your link and the code example. Link and example of code are from Places SearchBox() you are using Places Autocomplete(). Anyway, I do not understand what is the problem because if I write something (not complete) and press enter I get nothing which is expected (getPlace returns Object with property `name` as stated in docs). If I write something and push arrow down to provided result and press Enter I get the result.

Comment: Just tried the Place Autocomplete. Nothing happens when I press enter. So you might want to create your own function for that. Do you know how to check which key was pressed in an input?

Comment: It's just whenever I press enter a DIFFERENT 'form' is activated and NOT the google map..  @MrUpsidown I thought something like 'var keyCode = e.keyCode' but I might be mistaken.